# WPF - Image distorted after ImageSource changed during Binding trigger

Tags: wpf, binding, dpi, ivalueconverter, imagesource

So I have a an Image, which has a Source property. That property is using Binding to get `ImageSource` property from a ViewModel. The Binding is using `IValueConverter` however and the converter is returning different `ImageSource` based on whether the mouse is over the control. Because the screen has high DPI and because of how the control looks, some properties had to be set to the Image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Filter.IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledToImageSourceConverter}}"
       UseLayoutRounding="False"
       Stretch="None"
       Width="45"
       Height="45"
       Cursor="Hand" />
```

The code works... sort of. Upon hovering the mouse over the control, the image changes, but doesn't adjust.

No hover - image nicely sized:

[image: A nicely sized bitmap]

With hover - image is distorted:

[image]

The Image is Content of a Button, Button has a custom `ControlTemplate` to get rid of it's graphics. No `VisualStateGroups` set. Is this some WPF trickery I'm missing that everybody else knows about, or is this my doing?

Comment: Try Stretch="Uniform"

Comment: What's the difference between the images? Are they the same size?

Comment: Do the images have the same dpi settings in their headers?

Comment: Yes, the images are identical as far as I can tell from the file information. I'm using Irfan View.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stretch="Uniform"
```

as suggested by PJRobot actually works. It's not ideal as my images are different sizes and the data template will have account for that, but at least the image size remains constant.

Thanks.